# Forward Struct Declaration in C; not working

Tags: c, struct, header-files, forward-declaration

I read all the other posts with no success yet (eg [forward declaration of a struct in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999512/forward-declaration-of-a-struct-in-c))

There are two header files with functions which reference structs from each others' headers.
Forward declaration isn't working...surely because i'm still doing it incorrectly:) Thoughts?

**foo.h:**

```
typedef struct{
...
}foostruct;
extern foostruct fooStruct; //this struct used in foo.c and other c files
typedef struct barstruct; //attempt at forward declaration
void fooFctn(barstruct *barVar); //needs definition from bar.h
```

**bar.h:**

```
typedef struct{
...
}barstruct;
extern barstruct barStruct; //this struct used in bar.c and other c files
typedef struct foostruct; //attempt at forward declaration
void fooFctn(foostruct *fooVar); //needs definition from foo.h
```

The error is

```
error: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [-Werror]
src/search.h:123:18: error: unknown type name 'foostruct'
```

Since these structs were typedef-d originally i also tried just "foostruct;" without the identifier which (of course) doesn't work, likewise declaring "typedef struct fooVar foostruct" generates a redefinition error.

Comment: You don't typedef anything, hence the “useless storage class specifier” message (`typedef` is a storage class specifier).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `foo.h`, this code:

```
typedef struct barstruct;
```

is a degenerate `typedef` that announces that `struct barstruct` exists, but does not give an alternative name for it (hence the 'useless storage class specifier in empty declaration' warning/error).  You need:

```
typedef struct barstruct barstruct;
```

Then the code will work properly in `foo.h`.  The corresponding change is needed in `bar.h` for `struct foostruct`.

However, that still leaves you with a problem.  The type `barstruct` declared in `foo.h` is not identical to the type `barstruct` declared in `bar.h` (because one is a tagged structure and one is a tagless structure).  There are several ways around this.  In C11 (but not C99 or C89), you can repeat a `typedef` if they're identical.

You would therefore have the two `typedef` lines:

```
typedef struct barstruct barstruct;
typedef struct foostruct foostruct;
```

at the top of the headers, and then define in `bar.h`:

```
struct barstruct { … };
```

and in `foo.h`:

```
struct foostruct { … };
```

If compatibility with earlier versions of C is important, then you need to consider using `struct barstruct` and `struct foostruct` in the function declarations:

#### `foo.h`

```
typedef struct foostruct foostruct;

struct foostruct
{
   …
};

extern foostruct fooStruct;
struct barstruct;
void fooFctn(struct barstruct *barVar);
```

and analogously for `bar.h`.  This will also work with C11, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Properly typedef your struct should resolve your problem.

```
typedef struct foostruct foostruct;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Structures and tags**

`struct { ... };` is an anonymous structure. It is only useful with typedefs, and only when that typedef name is used and declared in that one file. In other words, it cannot be used with forward declarations.

However, `struct X { ... };` is a structure of type `struct X`. It can be used for forward declarations. Note that `X` is just the tag name used to denote a specific structure type, not the actual type. The tag name is used to distinguish between other declared structure types. This confuses people sometimes, so an example might help. Note that all of the declared structure types are different:

```
/* Declare an anonymous structure. */
struct {
    int n;
};

/* Another anonymous structure. It in different from the previous one. */
struct {
    double d;
};

/* Declare a structure of type `struct bar'. */
struct bar {
    int n;
};

/* Declare a structure of type `struct foo'. */
struct foo {
    int n;
};


/* Declare a variable `var' of type `struct foo'. */
struct foo var;

/* Unless a typedef for the `foo' type exists, or a preprocessor macro is used to replace `foo' with an actual type, this is a compilation error. */
foo var2;
```

Note that if you attempt to declare two structures with the same tag name, it is an error.

**typedefs**

The form for a typedef is the same as for a variable declaration with no initializer:

```
typedef TYPE NAME;
```

For example:

```
typedef int Integer;
```

declares the `Integer` type to be the same as `int`. The same can be done with structures:

```
/* Typedef'd anonymous structure */
typedef struct {
    int foo;
} fooBType;

/* Typedef'd `struct foostruct' structure */
typedef struct foostruct {
    int foo;
} fooGType;
```

The difference between the two:

- forward declarations of the structure type referenced by `fooBType` in other files are not possible because the structure referenced by `fooBType` is anonymous
- forward declarations of the structure type `struct foostruct` referenced by `fooGType` are possible because the type is able to be referenced by the structure tag and the `struct` keyword, as in `struct foostruct` or `typedef struct foostruct fooGType;`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that an anonymous structure can be used outside a `typedef`; you can write `struct { … } x, y;` and then use `x` and `y` in the scope of the declaration.  It is a corner case, but can occasionally be useful — let's make that usable; it is more useful to add the tag.  The two anonymous structures in your example are useless; they are neither a part of a `typedef` nor defining anything.  That doesn't matter for pedagogical purposes as long as both you and the OP are aware of it.