# data structure linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Can someone explain to me how in this code for defining a node in linked list we can define a pointer of node type before we finish declaring node itself ?

```
struct node

{ int data;
  struct node* next;  // Problem in this line,how we declared a node type pointer      
                      //before the node actually gets created . 
} var_node;
```

Comment: 'struct node;' forward declaration.  There are, like, thousands of dups of this.

Comment: @MartinJames  How is this forward declaration ?

Comment: `struct node` declares the existence of a struct called node _before_ the `{ int data ... }` definition. This is a forward declaration only with respect to the definition itself, but it's still a forward declaration.

Answer (score 1):

To declare a pointer to a struct, the compiler doesn't need to know the struct layout. It only needs to know that such a struct exists.

When compiling the code, the compiler adds the struct name to the list of known structs before it starts compiling the struct fields.

So when it comes to the struct field `next` it knows that a struct named `node` exists.

The standard says:

> 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> Constraints
>
> A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence,
> a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
> of itself),

Comment: thanks @klas . i will keep all this in mind .

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, it's unclear what problem you're having but hopefully this answers the question.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node A;
    A.data = 0;
    A.next = 0;

    struct node B;
    B.data = 1;
    B.next = &A;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `You need to use forward decleration`  Why ?

Comment: what is forward declaration could u explain ? I searched in the tags also on stackoverflow but not understanding it . Could some1 explain me that in layman terms ?

Comment: @VivekVashishta for fowrard declaration [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999512/forward-declaration-of-a-struct-in-c), but here there is no need to declare any forward declaration.

Comment: @ameyCU Good point, you don't seem to need forward decleration at all. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem here:

```
struct node    
{
  int data;
  struct node* next;  // there is no problem here, the only thing the compiler
                      // needs to know is that "struct node" exists and he knows that
                      // because we are right in the middle of the declaration
                      // of the struct. We only declare a pointer to
                      // struct node here and therefore the compiler does not need
                      // to know the complete structure of struct node here.
} var_node;
```

On the other hand this will not work:

```
struct node
{ 
  int data;
  struct node next;
} var_node;
```

because that is a recursive declaration which makes no sense: `struct node` would contain another `struct node` which contains another `struct node` and so on.