# Linked list of alternating structure type in c

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

This is a question about the c language,

I'm trying to create structures with two types, A and B.
Such that I can declare a linked list `A->B->A->B...`

My question is, "how do I declare the types such that I can create a linked list A->B->A->B->...?"

Comment: I can't figure out how the last part relates to the question of "how do I declare the types such that I can create a linked list A->B->A->B->...?"

Comment: Also, what have you tried, and how didn't it work?

Comment: Got my crystal ball out.  It says that you tried this and had compile errors.  And you need to forward-declare your structs.  Good job, crystal ball! =)

Comment: I'm sorry, your whole question is spaghetti. Perhaps if you showed some real code to illustrate what you mean it would be clearer.

Comment: `struct A; struct B { struct A *ptr; }; struct A { struct B *ptr; };`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999512/forward-declaration-of-a-struct-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that either type has to know about the other one to be able to be defined. It does not matter in which order you define your types, however you must tell the first one you define that the second one exists, but will be defined later. This is called forward declaration, see the link in BostonBooks's comment. In C (and C++, too, btw) this will look as this:

```
struct B;
struct A
{
    struct B* next;
};
struct B
{
    struct A* next;
};
```

(I stole the code from M.M's comment...)